# Использование одного кода для нескольких страниц сайта

Tags: php, шаблоны, оптимизация-сайтов, site, page

У меня есть сайт, который состоит из нескольких страниц, у которых меню, шапка, ноги, подключение скриптов и т.д. одни и те же и разное только содержимое.

Поэтому хочу сделать единый файл `routine.php`, который содержит все одинаковые куски. А все страницы по сути будут вызывать этот файл и указывать ему только разное содержимое (которое можно будет в многостроковую переменную разместить).

Подскажите, правильный ли это подход? И как то лучше реализовать.

Comment: Может стоит посмотреть в сторону twig???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

к примеру ...

```
class Html {

    private static $data = [];

//Принимает массив данных
  public static function setData ($data = []) {

        self::$data = $data;
        foreach (self::$data as $key => $val) {
            self::$data[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    public static function getData () {
        return self::$data;
    }
    //на нужной странице выводит шапку с нужным наполнением
    public static function viewHeader () {

        echo "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset=".self::$data['charSet'].">
        <meta name='description' content=".self::$data['description'].">
        <meta name='keywords' content=".self::$data['keyWords'].">
        <link href='style/main.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <title>".self::$data['title']."</title>
        </head>
        <body>";
    }

    public function __destruct () {

    }
}
//index.php
include ('путь к файлу с классом');
Html::setData ([charSet=>"utf-8", description=>"О сайте", keyWords=>"Ключевые слова", title=>"Главная страница"]);
Html::viewHeader();
```

Answer (score -1):

Пишешь в файле `routine.php` функции и подключаешь его через  `include("путь к файлу /routine.php");` в нужном месте или можно создать класс и реализовать в нем нужные методы и свойства.